# Angular2-moment, format minutes to

Tags: angular, angular2-moment

These are minutes : 1956

I want to format these minutes to : HH:mm

I'm using angular2-moment.

I've tried : `1956 | amDuration:'minutes' | amDateFormat: 'HH:mm'`

But I get "Invalid date"

What do i have to do to make it work ?

Comment: `amDateFormat` requires a date, whereas you have a duration. What does 1956 represent?

Comment: 1956 represent "1956 minutes"

Comment: ...thanks? *"In 1956 minutes"*? *"1956 minutes ago"*? *"Ran for 1956 minutes"*?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. I want format : 1956 to 32h36min. And it represents a travel time

Comment: var hours = moment.duration(1956, 'minutes').asHours();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
moment.duration(1956, "minutes").format("h [hrs], m [min]");
// "32 hrs, 36 min"
```

Comment: Thanks but there is no way with angular2-moment filter ?

Comment: Need to use import 'moment-duration-format'; to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
countdown = 600;

{{ (countdown | amFromUnix) | amDateFormat: 'mm:ss' }}

//Output 10:00
```